# Place Django admin forms in different files

Tags: django, forms, model, admin

In Django, is it possible to place forms for models in the admin interface into different files per app? The same as can be done for [model files](http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/11/splitting-up-django-models/).

E.g. instead of:

```
app/admin.py

  class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    [...]

  class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

    [...]
```

I'd have

```
app/admin/personadmin.py

  class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    [...]

app/admin/caradmin.py

  class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)

    [...]
```

I would like to do this without changing Django code.

It's just for overview, I know it doesn't open up new possibilies for the functioning of the site.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried creating an `__init__.py` file under the admin directory?

The contents would look like:

```
from personadmin import PersonAdmin
from caradmin import CarAdmin
```

Just follow the instructions you linked to, but replace "models" with "admin". Try it and see if it works. I'd be surprised if it doesn't.

Comment: Hell Evan, thanks for the answer. That does make them available for importing, but they aren't found by admin.autodiscover() so they do not appear, regretably.

Comment: Sorry, I must have tried something in the wrong order, it's actually working now if I remove the explicit imports!

Answer (score 1):

You can put them wherever you like, you just have to import them manually some place that gets loaded at runtime (settings.py, urls.py, etc.). You can't use `admin.autodiscover()` any more because that's what it's actually doing: importing all the admin.py files in all your apps.

Although, you probably could still use `admin.autodiscover()` if you put all your imports in the admin.py files themselves. You would also need to add all the classes in your separated files to `__all__` in your admin.py files, at that point.

Comment: Hello Chris, thanks for the answer. Importing the models from admin.py does indeed work, thanks. It's certainly an improvement this way, though if there's any more elegant way I'd gladly hear :-)

Comment: Not really. Although, checking out how imports are done in the actual Django source may be instructive. They use just about every feasible method of including one thing in another there ;).

Comment: @ChrisPratt i am new to django. what you are saying is  i can put my models inside model folder but i need to import them in admin.py. If that's right how do i import from a model folder located at the same level as admin.py