# Django: xyz.fieldsets[0][1]['fields'] refers to field '123' that is missing from the form

Tags: django, admin, readonly

I have little doubt that this will be a really stupid question. But I really can't figure it out so I'll ask it anyway.

In /svsite/src/svsite/member/models/svuser.py (a little unusual location, see this question [Place Django admin forms in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144631/place-django-admin-forms-in-different-files)).

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin, UserChangeForm as DjangoUserChangeForm
from svsite.member.models.svuser import svUser

class UserChangeForm(DjangoUserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        pass

class svUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login', 'last_update', )

    fieldsets = \
    (
        (
            'Login',
            {
                'classes': ('collapse', ),
                'fields':
                (
                    'username',
                    'password',
                    'is_active',
                    'email_verified',
                    'awaiting_user_confirmation',
                ), 
            }
        ),
        (
            'Personal info',
            {
                'fields':
                (
                    'first_name',
                    'middle_name',
                    'last_name', 
                ), 
            }
        ),
    )
[...]
```

In the model I have at /svsite/src/svsite/member/admin/svuser.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class svUser(User):
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    awaiting_user_confirmation = models.BooleanField(
        _('approved by board'), default = False, help_text=_('This user\'s identity was confirmed by the board or another authority.'))
[...]
```

The error I get:

```
'svUserAdmin.fieldsets[0][1]['fields']' refers to field 'password' that is missing from the form.
```

If I comment password, the error moves to the next field. Independent if it's a default user model field or one I added in the svUser inherited from user. Very surprisingly (to me), username seems to be the only field that works, no problems on that one.

I found this question [Django ModelAdmin - fieldsets ... field 'date' missing from the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516799/django-modeladmin-fieldsets-field-date-missing-from-the-form) and even though the fields are not auto_now, I added them to readonly_fields and that made the error go away. Obviously though, making all fields read-only is not an option.

It's probably something stupid not really related to code but I really can't find it, seems to me it really should be working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be because you're using a `ModelForm` for a model that you are not editing.

I tried a simliar situation and got a similar error pattern.

```
class UserChangeForm(DjangoUserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = svUser # update the model - default form points to User
```